# Перебить стиль родительского блока

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как могу перебить style.display родительского span-а?
Есть такая разметка:

```
<td>...</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <span class="class1 ..." style="display:none">
        <span class="class2 ..." title="Вот это должно отображаться, но из-за стиля родительского span-a не отображается">
        <img src="...">
        </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
<td>...</td>
```

На странице должна отображаться картинка из спана с классом - `class2`, но из-за стиля `display:none` в спана с классом - `class1` он скрыт. Понимаю, что правильно будет найти откуда тянется этот стиль и при каких условиях, так как не на всех страницах картинка скрыта, но такой возможности нет. Подскажите, как отключить/перебить/изменить `display:none` и отрисовать картинку?

Answer (score 0):

Так проверяли?

```
.class1 {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Но лучше всё же найти, где конкретно прописывается скрытие и убрать, потому что потом могут возникнуть какие-нибудь проблемы...

Comment: Да, так пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: @mysqllearn, тогда приводите полный пример. Потому что или Вы где-то ошиблись, или у Вас уже в стилях class2 перебит display на none, или перебито ещё выше